# How to replace "\\\\" with "\\" in a string?

Tags: c#, string, file, char

The file path is having 4 slashes. I need only 2 slashes. How to replace it?

For eg : `"C:\\\\abc\\\\def\\\\\\\\ghi\\\\"`

I need `"C:\\\\abc\\\\def\\\\ghi\\\\"`

Comment: [Replace(String, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-5.0#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_)?

Comment: Where do you get this path? Is something shown you by Visual Studio through some part of its interface?

Comment: tip: `var path=@"C:\abc\def\ghi\";` [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)

Comment: Your strings don’t have two backslashes either. The two backslashes are just a visual representation for one backslash by showing it escaped with the escape character. In general you should use verbatim strings with file pathes, I.e. `@"C:\abc\def\ghi\"` which is the same you have written but more legible. With that being said it becomes easy to correct two backslashes (which get visualized as four) by doing `path = path.Replace(@"\\", @"\");`.

Comment: Min your file path is kinda weird but  Kyle Wang comment is the real answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

`var f = "C:\\abc\\def\\\\ghi\\".Replace(@"\\", @"\");`

I tried with:
`Console.WriteLine("C:\\abc\\def\\\\ghi\\".Replace(@"\\", @"\"));`
it works fine.